# How to programmatically apply MapXtreme Themes

Tags: gis, mapxtreme

I maintain  a Desktop application using MapXtreme 7.0 and I have
trouble finding much documentation or useful examples (I do have the
pdfs, samples etc that come on the install discs)

Currently I am trying to programmaticly apply an IndividualValueTheme
to a FeatureLayer.  I can apply a standard default theme,  I can also
show a ModifyIndValueThemeDlg and let the user change the theme.
However what I want to do is apply my own theme to the layer without
user intervention.

The following code attempts to do this but results in the Layer
showing with the default IndividualValueTheme (ie not with my styles)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
void ApplyTheme(FeatureLayer lyr)
{
    if (lyr.Modifiers.Contains(HarvOpsTheme) || lyr.Modifiers.Contains(HarvOpsRangedTheme))
        return;
    HarvOpsTheme = new IndividualValueTheme(lyr, "iOperationType","HarvOpsTheme");
    lyr.Modifiers.Append(HarvOpsTheme);
    HarvOpsTheme.Bins[0].Style.ApplyStyle(GetHollowAreaStyle(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0)));
    HarvOpsTheme.Bins[1].Style.ApplyStyle(GetHollowAreaStyle(Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 0)));
    HarvOpsTheme.Bins[2].Style.ApplyStyle(GetHollowAreaStyle(Color.FromArgb(128, 128, 0)));
    HarvOpsTheme.Bins[3].Style.ApplyStyle(GetHollowAreaStyle(Color.FromArgb(192, 128, 0)));
    HarvOpsTheme.Bins[4].Style.ApplyStyle(GetHollowAreaStyle(Color.FromArgb(0, 128, 0)));
    HarvOpsTheme.Bins[5].Style.ApplyStyle(GetHollowAreaStyle(Color.FromArgb(0, 205, 128)));
    HarvOpsTheme.Bins[6].Style.ApplyStyle(GetHollowAreaStyle(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0)));

    HarvOpsTheme.Apply(HarvOpsTheme);
    HarvOpsTheme.RecomputeStyles();

    lyr.Invalidate();
}

AreaStyle GetHollowAreaStyle(Color color)
{
    return new AreaStyle
    {
        Interior = StockStyles.HollowFillStyle(),
        Border = new SimpleLineStyle(new LineWidth(1,LineWidthUnit.Pixel), 1, color)
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Individual Theme only,recomputing styles causes to regenerate the first theming result.After user changes styles by [Bins] you do not need to recompute them again.

In short, simply remove the line and let the magic happen

```
HarvOpsTheme.RecomputeStyles();
```

Best Regards

Comment: That may well have been a bug in my code but with or without that line no 'magic' ever happened.  Thankfully MapXtreme is now all but historical.

Comment: I agree with history part of Mapxtreme's never documented coding style and a year+ later coming response of yours.